# Compile Error: Named argument not found; The highlights ReadOnly:=True

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving the error: "Compile Error:  Named argument not found" when running the below code.  The error highlights the ReadOnly:=True statement.

```
Sub GetSheets()
 'Update ExcelJunction.com
 Path = "C:\Users\chad.carlisle\Documents\CBMS\"
 Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
 Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadyOnly:=True
 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Next Sheet
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
 Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
ReadyOnly:=True
```

with:

```
ReadOnly:=True
```

*(there may be other errors)*